# Starting bottle web server through systemd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle, systemd

I am trying to start a bottle web app I wrote using systemd. I made the file `/etc/systemd/user/bottle.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Bottled fax service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=fax
Group=fax
WorkingDirectory=/home/fax/bottlefax/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python3 server.py
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Restart=always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=bottle.target
```

However, when I try to start it, it fails and this is printed in `journalctl`:

```
Jun 10 17:33:31 nano systemd[1]: Started Bottled fax service.
Jun 10 17:33:31 nano systemd[1]: Starting Bottled fax service...
Jun 10 17:33:31 nano systemd[2380]: Failed at step GROUP spawning /usr/bin/env: No such process
Jun 10 17:33:31 nano systemd[1]: bottle.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
Jun 10 17:33:31 nano systemd[1]: Unit bottle.service entered failed state.
Jun 10 17:33:31 nano systemd[1]: bottle.service failed.
```

How should I fix this?

Edit:

Changing to `/usr/bin/python3` as others have suggested results in the same error (changed file though):

```
Jun 10 18:43:48 nano systemd[1]: Started Bottled fax service.
Jun 10 18:43:48 nano systemd[1]: Starting Bottled fax service...
Jun 10 18:43:48 nano systemd[2579]: Failed at step GROUP spawning /usr/bin/python3: No such process
Jun 10 18:43:48 nano systemd[1]: bottle.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
Jun 10 18:43:48 nano systemd[1]: Unit bottle.service entered failed state.
Jun 10 18:43:48 nano systemd[1]: bottle.service failed.
```

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/bin/env` is what you want? How about `/usr/bin/python3`?

Answer (score 4):

I would have commented but I can't :/

Have you tried something like with an absolute path ?

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your/server.py
```

That's the only issue I can see here.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this error, is if you have created a system user by running `adduser --system`, and have not created the associated group.